# Combobox change not updating my View in WPF MVVM

Tags: mvvm

[enter link description here](https://pastebin.com/hnEhXyEL)I have a combo-box and checkbox,when the combo-box change event is fired the checkbox should bind with check/un-check...My combo-box event gives the data of checked/unchecked but the view does not gets updated.
How can i achieve this?

ViewModel.cs

```
       private ObservableCollection<string> _listData;
    public ObservableCollection<string> ListData
    {
        get { return _listData; }
        set { _listData = value; OnPropertyChanged("ListData"); }

    }
    private ObservableCollection<chkList> _modulesData;
    public ObservableCollection<chkList> ModulesData
    {
        get { return _modulesData; }
        set { _modulesData = value; OnPropertyChanged("ModulesData"); }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<chkList> _userModules;
    public ObservableCollection<chkList> UserModules
    {
        get { return _userModules; }
        set { _userModules = value; OnPropertyChanged("UserModules"); }
    }

    public UserModuleMappingViewModel()
    {
        GetListData();
        GetModulesData();
    }
    private void GetListData()
    {
        ListData = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        UserModuleMapping model = new UserModuleMapping();
        ListData = model.GetListData();
        comboBoxItems = new CollectionView(model.GetListData());
        comboBoxItems.MoveCurrentTo(ListData[0]);
        comboBoxItems.CurrentChanged += ComboBoxItems_CurrentChanged;
    }
    private void GetModulesData()
    {
        ModulesData = new ObservableCollection<chkList>();
        UserModuleMapping model = new UserModuleMapping();
        ModulesData = model.getModules();
        checkboxItems = new CollectionView(model.getModules());
        checkboxItems.MoveCurrentTo(ModulesData[0].ToString());
    }
    private void GetUserModules()
    {
        UserModules = new ObservableCollection<chkList>();
        UserModuleMapping model = new UserModuleMapping();
        UserModules = model.getuserModules(user_Id);
        checkboxItemsUpdated = new CollectionView(model.getuserModules(user_Id));
        checkboxItemsUpdated.MoveCurrentTo(UserModules[0].ToString());


    }
    private void ComboBoxItems_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Loaded)
        {
            user_Id = (((CollectionView)sender).CurrentItem).ToString();
            GetUserModules();

        }
        Loaded = true;

    }
```

I have added the view model code above

Comment: Please post your code / xaml

Comment: Add `UpdateSourceTrigger =PropertyChanged` to your binding.

Comment: I don't see the binding relationship between the combobox and the checkbox. Can you highlight that part of the code?

Comment: Where should I add update source property?I am new in MVVM so kindly cooperate with my mistakes

Comment: @Rohit Add it to your `IsChecked` property.

Comment: @arcticwhite: I added but still it didn't work.I guess I am missing something more

Comment: @Rohit Could you post your `ViewModel` code?

Comment: @arcticwhite I posted the view model code by replacing the XAML file as it was not allowing me to post entire code

Comment: @Rohit Darn, I need both, if you can paste all your code in pastebin and post the url here.

Comment: @arcticwhite I have shared the link  https://pastebin.com/hnEhXyEL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing your code, I would suggest you to make this kind of changes to your code.

Your combobox collection is `CollectionView`, I would suggest you to change it to `List<your_model>`, `IEnumerable<your_model>` or `ObservableCollection<your_model>`.

Then you can create property who will represent your `SelectedItem`.

```
private my_model _selectedItem;

public my_model SelectedItem 
{
    get { return _selectedItem; }
    set 
    {
        _selectedItem = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
    }
}
```

In the setter, add your code who will load your data depending on the value...

```
.
.
.
set 
{
    _selectedItem = value;
    user_Id = (((CollectionView) sender).CurrentItem).ToString();
    GetUserModules();
    OnPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
}
```

More about each of the list types you can read here:

- [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [IList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Sir,I will try and let you know the result...I'm very thankful for your help till now

Comment: @Rohit Feel free to ask if you get stuck in the solution.

Comment: Now I am not able to populate the combobox using Observable Collection...Combobox is filled with Projectname.objectname...Any type conversion is required?....Itemsource property in Xaml of Combobox is not proper as per my understanding

Comment: @Rohit Excelent, that will be easy to fix.
Inside `Combobox (XAML)` there are two properties who you need to define. The `DisplayMemberPath` and `SelectedValuePath`. The `DisplayMemberPath` should be equal to your property who you are showing to the users, and the `SelectedValuePath` should be the value member (mostly the primary key).
Sample `<ComboBox ItemsSource="..."   DisplayMemberPath="YourNameProperty"
                  SelectedValuePath="SomeIDProperty" ...>`

Comment: I overcome the above issues now my combo box is binding dynamically as well as checkbox contents..but on combo change break point is going there,the method also executes but my view does not change..

Comment: Add an `OnPropertyChanged("YourView")`

Comment: I added OnPropertyChanged("YourView") in the setter property of _mySelectedItem.It didnt Worked...Where should i place the line of code!

Comment: This is the method who you are calling `GetUserModules()`? It should update view?

Comment: Yes exactly that is the method and yes after that itself my view should update

Comment: Check inside the method you have this line of code` checkboxItemsUpdated = new CollectionView(model.getuserModules(user_Id));`
But property `checkboxItemsUpdated` is not binded to your view control. Since you have binded your `comboBoxItems` with `Combobox` just set instead of `checkboxItemsUpdated` to`comboBoxItems`. There is no need for new collection, just update your current.

Comment: Yes sir I have tried that....but now you asked me not to use collection view then how will it work?

Comment: Instead of `checkboxItemsUpdated = new CollectionView(model.getuserModules(user_Id));`
Just write `comboBoxItems = new ObservableCollection<your_model>(model.getUserModules(user_Id));`
`OnPropertyChanged("comboBoxItems ");`

Comment: I tried it above piece of code but i failed,getuserModules(user_Id) in this I am not passing the user_id instead i am passing the value of _selectedItem which is the same...

Comment: What happens, where does it fails? What is the error?

Comment: Sir you are marvelous It worked !!!!...tons of thanks for your kind support...You are amazing man...I want to be in contact with you..Will you share any info?

Comment: Yup it was last...:-)

Comment: How can i open a new window on the click of submenu?I have Menus and Submenus, on click of submenu i should view a new window

Comment: @Rohit Hey, if you haven't found any related thread in SO or Google to your problem, please open a new question, the community will help you :)